# Allow one instance of Google Maps API to control two maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have two versions of the same map on my page: one is made smaller via CSS and is displayed in a sidebar. The other is larger, and it opens in a lightbox when an png overlaid on top of the small map is clicked. The website is built on Drupal. The small map is in a block and the large map is on its own node page.  Both of these content items have the Google maps API js file referenced.

When I click the sidebar map link, Chrome's error console tells me "Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. ". I tried removing the Google maps API js reference from the light-box map, but it does not show the large map at all when I click the sidebar map link. It all works fine in FireFox when both maps have the Google Maps API js; it does not work in IE, Chrome, and Safari.

Any tips on how I might be able to get this to work correctly? Is there a way to dynamically "kill" the small sidebar map's js when the link is clicked and the large map opens in the light-box?

Comment: It should work with only one include of the API.  Without any information as to what your code or the includes currently look like or what you did to try to remove one, it is hard to help.  Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message states, you should only include the API once. You can create any number of map instances with a single load of the API.

Since you always load the small map, one easy solution would be to simply remove the Maps API `<script>` tag or `drupal_add_js()` call from the node that creates the large lightbox map. Of course you won't be able to view the map in that node any more if you open it as a standalone page; it will only work as part of your page that already includes the Maps API.

Or, you could conditionally include the Maps API script only once on the page. My PHP and Drupal coding is a bit rusty, but I think it would look something like this:

```
if( ! $mapsApiLoaded ) {
    $mapsApiLoaded = TRUE;
    drupal_add_js(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',
        'external'
    );
}
```

Use that code in your block and your node instead of a bare `drupal_add_js()` call or `<script>` tag and it should load the API only once.

(And of course if you are doing vehicle tracking or the like, `sensor=false` should read `sensor=true` as required by the [Maps API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)).

Or here is [another approach to loading a .js file once in Drupal](http://technology.blue-bag.com/drupaladdjs-tip-checking-javascript-already-added-page).

Interestingly enough, there was a discussion many years ago about [adding a "load only once" feature](https://drupal.org/node/105783) to the [`drupal_add_js()` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), but it was resolved as "wontfix". :-(

You can also do something similar in pure JavaScript. Simply use `document.write()` to write the `<script>` tag for the Maps API after checking that it hasn't already been loaded:

```
<script>
    function loadMapsAPI() {
        if( window.google && google.maps )
            return;
        document.write(
            '<script src="',
                'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
                '?v=3&sensor=false',
            '">',
            '<\/script>'
        );
    }
</script>
```

Test it with:

```
<script>
    loadMapsAPI();
</script>

<script>
    loadMapsAPI();
</script>

<script>
    // Normal Maps API initialization code here
</script>
```

Note that you *can't* do it this way:

```
<script>
    loadMapsAPI();
    // Normal Maps API initialization code here
</script>
```

This is because the `document.write()` in `loadMapsAPI()` writes out the API's `<script>` tag *after* the current `<script>` tag. So if you put that call and the rest of the map initialization in the same `<script>` tag they will be in the wrong order:

```
<script>
    loadMapsAPI();
    // Normal Maps API initialization code here
</script>
... The Maps API <script> generated by document.write is *here* ...
```

It is OK to combine the `loadMapsAPI()` function definition and call in the same `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
    function loadMapsAPI() {
        if( window.google && google.maps )
            return;
        document.write(
            '<script src="',
                'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
                '?v=3&sensor=false',
            '">',
            '<\/script>'
        );
    }
    loadMapsAPI();
</script>
```

Or even not make it a function:

```
<script>
    if( !( window.google && google.maps ) ) {
        document.write(
            '<script src="',
                'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
                '?v=3&sensor=false',
            '">',
            '<\/script>'
        );
    }
</script>
```

Then you'd repeat that `<script>` tag wherever you need it.

Now if you're generating these `<script>` tags from PHP code, there's probably some more escaping and quoting to worry about, but I'll let you figure that part out since I'm not much of a PHP expert.

Comment: The code snippet you provided seems to do the trick! Thank you! My only issue now is that the pop-up map displays this error message:  

Error message 
Notice: Undefined variable: mapsApiLoaded in eval() (line 2 of /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Any idea what would cause that and how it can be fixed?

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I'm not sure about that undefined variable message, but does it literally refer to `mapsApiLoaded` and not `$mapsApiLoaded`? Could it be just a missing `$`? Sorry, I'm not much of a PHP expert although I've done a bit of PHP and Drupal work. An alternative could be a pure JavaScript solution using `document.write()` to write the script tag. I can add something to the answer to give some ideas on that if it would be helpful.

Comment: Michael Geary, the document.write() solution would be much appreciated. Please do. Thanks!

Comment: I added a `document.write()` example. It's just the JavaScript code; you'll probably need to figure out the proper quoting and escaping to use this from PHP.